# How to set an X property that is an array of strings?

Tags: x11

```
$ xprop -root _XKB_RULES_NAMES
_XKB_RULES_NAMES(STRING) = "evdev", "pc104", "us", "altgr-intl", ""
```

I can see that this property on the root window contains five strings. But I found no way with `xprop` to set it! The tricky part is to set a *string array* so that it looks like shown above.

If `xprop` can’t do it another tool is fine, too.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with `xprop` (due to [null chars](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11229#c3))... unless you patch it (so that `8s` would accept a comma delimited string as an array, similar to what this guy did [here](https://github.com/Bad-ptr/xsetprop) for `32a`).

Comment: @don_crissti any other program can? Or up to 50 python lines, maybe?

Comment: None that I'm aware of, alas. The few `py` bindings that I have occasionally played with, could only `get` the values, not `set` them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found no way with `xprop`. So I wrote [xproperty](https://github.com/siemer/xproperty), which can do that. It’s a little Python program on github.

Comment: @don_crissti It had 54 lines the last time I checked...